# How do I change all negative values in a column to 0

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column named Cur_bal in power bi I just want to know what day function could help me change all negative a to 0 and keep all other values the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a calculated column or a measure. The formula for a calculated column would be:

```
Cur_Bal - Positive_Only = 
IF ( 'Table'[Cur_Bal] < 0, 0, 'Table'[Cur_Bal] )
```

Once you have that, you can use it in an implicit or explicit measure to sum up the total.

For a measure, it would look like this:

```
Cur_Bal - Positive_Only (measure) = 
CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Cur_Bal] ), 'Table'[Cur_Bal] > 0 )
```

The measure uses a CALCULATE function with a simple filter on Cur_bal column.

[Link to image of output sample table...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/468S2.png)